# How can I show less or more images based on the device type/size?

Tags: meteor, web, responsive-design

I have a responsive design for a website, so that it shows correctly either in desktop or mobile. My app is sort of a video gallery. (I'm using blaze, if that's relevant.)

However I would like to change the number of previews in desktop (about 9) and in mobile (probably 3), because a full screen in a desktop is different from a full screen in a mobile device.

I know how to only show some of the content by using CSS to hide/show different layouts on different viewports. However I'm trying to limit the data downloaded by the app, and not the data shown.

I was thinking I could achieve this by filtering my collection, however how do I identify the client device/viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered building logic into your CSS using @media queries? This would manipulate your page display based on viewport, not device, though this is usually what you want anyway and it will require less maintenance going forward.

There are any number of ways you could do this. Here's a example where you tag the blocks you want to show on mobile with `class="show-mobile"`. Then you have a media query to hide all the blocks which don't have this class when the the viewport is over 767px.

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/aWBXXM

Hope this helps!

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="show-mobile">one</li>
    <li class="show-mobile">two</li>
    <li class="show-mobile">three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  li{display:none;}
  li.show-mobile{display:inline-block;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, but I would like to limit the number of links downloaded by the app, and not the number of links shown by CSS. I'll edit the question to make it more clear.